# Polynomial in n code? what does it mean

Tags: algorithm

What does it mean when someone says that the code is polynomial in `n`? And then how does one make sure that his code is polynomial in `n`?

Comment: Hard to know the context in which that was said, but in all probability the person is referring to the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of the code. Very roughly, "polynomial in n" would mean that given an input of size n, the code will run in at most a constant factor of n^2 (or n^k where k is any positive integer) time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time

Comment: This isn't to do with [tag:python].

Comment: I wasn't sure which tag to use.

Comment: thank you @ajcr. I will check it out Peter